# How to disable autoresume of a ZFS-formatted drive on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, usb, external-hard-drive, zfs, suspend

I've bought an [external hard drive](http://www.verbatim-europe.co.uk/en_1/product_usb-3-0-desktop-hard-drive-2tb_5317_0_29012__1645.html). I want to use it with Ubuntu 11.04 (kernel 2.6.38-11-server) and the `zfs-fuse` package. I've successfully formatted the disk to [zfs](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+zfs/WebHome). The disk is suspending when it is inactive after a while.

The problem is that zfs can't access the disk after I manually resume it. I can use `sudo zpool clear` after the resume, but it's not really a solution for me.

There is `set usbcore.autosuspend=-1` in grub – I can see in a file `/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend` that its value is set to -1 – but it doesn't work.

How can I correctly disable autoresume? Or is it possible to create a "hook script" that will detach zfs devices before they are suspended and attach the zfs devices after resuming the disk?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use zfs-fuse, it's outdated. Use the modules from zfsonlinux.org - with Ubuntu, just add the ppa from Darik Horn for native zfs for Ubuntu:

https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/stable

This gives you ubuntu-zfs - Native ZFS filesystem metapackage for Ubuntu.

Follow instructions and FAQ from zfsonlinux.org/faq.html . For zfs automount, it's 1.14 in the FAQ.

I'm currently typing this on a zfs system which hibernates and suspends without issues.